# I am getting error while submitting the form for dropdown list in MVC 5 Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in which I have a dropdown list which is bound to database. It is populating the values and my dropdown shows the values as well, but when I am submitting the form an error like below occurs:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: items
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: items

I have bound the dropdown to the database but on post the controller is getting my class object which has a `gender` property. I check that my model object has the correct, selected value from the dropdown, but when it moves to the statement `modelstate.isvalid` it returns false.

```
public ActionResult Create(Registration registration)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        registration.ConfirmPassword = EncryptionLibrary.EncryptText(registration.ConfirmPassword);
        registration.Password= EncryptionLibrary.EncryptText(registration.Password);
        registration.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Registration.Add(registration);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.teacher = "Teacher account has been created Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        TempData["Faculty"] = "";
        var result = _IRegistration.AddFaculty(registration);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            TempData["Success"] = "Faculty Added Successfully";
            ModelState.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }
    return View(registration);
}
```

Below is my razor syntax for the dropdown to bind the values from viewbag:

```cs
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Gender, new SelectList(ViewBag.Gender, "Id", "Name"), "Please select", new { @id = "ddlFruits",@class="btn form-text" })
```

I want to save the gender dropdown value into the database although it is getting populated then why it is saying Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Registration class ?